# Understanding the structure of underscore.js code

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I saw this pattern in the [underscore source code](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js)  and many other open source JavaScript projects :

```
(function() {
 // the library code
}).call(this);
```

Anyone can explain what this pattern do ? and what is the benefits of using it ?

Why not just :

```
(function() {
 // the library code
}());
```

Comment: It sets `this` inside the function to the same as `this` outside the function.  (This usually is ran globally, so `this` is `window`.)

Comment: That doesn't explain it since, for underscore.js, `this` is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since both are equivalent in normal context I looked into the source and it was changed from the form you suggest to the current form 2 years ago with the following check-in comment:

"Added explicit definition of global context for compatibility with Adobe JS"

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/commit/aa916b8cfe565dc206d85c4cb74fbb6c499067a7

The check-in logs for the first version of Underscore with this change claims "Improved Underscore compatibility with Adobe's JS engine that can be used to script Illustrator, Photoshop, and friends."

http://underscorejs.org/  Version 1.4.3

So this change seems to have been made because Adobe's JavaScript engine did not conform to ES3 or ES5 at the time but with this change Underscore was made compatible with their variant.

If you are not planning on running your module in Adobe JS then you can use either form. If you are then it appears Adobe JS requires the form used by Underscore.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably to do with the `noConflict` feature if you happen to have multiple versions of underscore running at the same time.

`this` (`window`) is passed in so it can detect existing versions of `_`. Using this notation you avoid a hard reference to `window`, which is nice. There are also some minor performance benefits: variables in local scope resolve faster.

Alternatives could be:

```
(function () {
    // library
}(window)); // hard reference to window (not so nice)

(function () {
    // library
}({})); // this will break `noConflict` detection
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to wrap you whole code in an anonymous function. This way variable declared inside the function will remain private, so other scripts won't be able to access your code.

And `.call` is a function method. That will invoke the anonymouse function with passed argument as a value of `this`.

In this case whatever is the value of `this` is by default it's `window` object, will be available inside the anonymouse function to. Here is an example of it.

```
(function(a, b, c ){ // and other arguments
    // Here `this` will refer to document object.

    // And the variables declared here are compltly private

    // If you want any variable to make global use window object

    var someStuff = 'scret'; // Private

    function Lib(){
        return someStuff.length;
    }

    window.Lib = Lib; // This will be available to other scripts

}).call(document, a, b, c);
```

This kind of wrapper is generally generated by preprocessor languages like [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**First part**:

```
var x = 1; // `x` is in the global scope

(function() {
 var y = x; // `y` is in the current function's scope
}());

x = y; // Here `x` becomes `undefined` because `y` is not declared in this "outer" scope
```

As to the "**why**" - it's a simple technique to keep out of trouble (no "memory leaks" [all internally declared vars are void when function ends], no declaration collision etc').

**Second part**:
As for the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (there's also [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which is similar) version, it's simply a matter of context.
The author wants that the context of the anonymous function (that function above) will have its `this` point to the same `this` of the outer scope.

Hope it's clear :)